# Tic-Tac-Toe Program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a Tic-Tac-Toe program that will determine if a given playing board is won by "X" "O" or a tie.

Obviously I know which games are won by who, but how can I get the program to check for that?

```
int check(int board[3][3]) {
//I've tried putting some code here, but nothing successful.  

return 0;
}

int main() {
// this is a three-dimensional array, three games of two-dimensional
// boards; just concern yourself about the two-dimensional boards
int games[3][3][3] = { 
    {  
        { -1,  0,  1 },  //O_X
        {  0,  1, -1 },  //_XO
        {  1, -1,  0 }   //XOX
    },
    {  
        {  0,  1,  1 },  //_XX
        { -1, -1, -1 },  //OOO
        {  1,  1,  0 }   //XX_
    },
    {  
        {  1,  1, -1 }, //XXO
        { -1, -1,  1 }, //OOX
        {  1,  1, -1 }  //XXO 
    }
};

for (int game = 0; game < 3; game++) {
    if (check(games[game]) == 1) {
        cout << "player X wins game " << game + 1 << endl;
    } else if (check(games[game]) == -1) {
        cout << "player O wins game " << game + 1 << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "game " << game + 1 << " is a cat game" << endl;
    }
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is a homework problem - You should show what you've tried, not expect us just to write the answer for you.

Comment: `Obviously I know which games are won by who, but how can I get the program to check for that?` make it check for the same conditions you would yourself to determine a winner

Comment: `I've tried putting some code here, but nothing successful.` What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
int check(int board[3][3]) {
     int winner = 0;

     // check line
     for( int i=0; i<3; ++i )
          { 
               if( board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][1] == board[i][2] && board[i][0] != 0)
                    winner = board[i][0];  
          }

     // check column
     for( int i=0; i<3; ++i )
          { 
               if( board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[1][i] == board[2][i] && board[0][i] != 0 )
                    winner = board[0][i];  
          }

     // check diagonal
     if( board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2] && board[1][1] != 0)
          winner = board[1][1];

     if( board[2][1] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[0][2] && board[1][1] != 0)
          winner = board[1][1];

return winner;
}
```

Comment: Giving the OP a full answer like that isn't really helping, as they'll fail the actual objective of solving their homework, and just be back next week asking for the the solution for their next problem, without ever actually learning anything

Comment: Adding to @benjymous, if the OP blindly copy-pastes this answer, their program will have a bug.

Comment: @BartvanNierop At least that means there's still a learning opportunity somewhere!